# Can we render a collection on top of another collection? (for overlays?)

Tags: eevee-render-engine

can we render multiple collections together to do things like animated infographics / overlays?

in realtime not in the compositor / render time

edit:
example - Collection 1 is a camera pointed at a few planes with UV / alpha / text objects (like a game UI)

collection 2 is a 3d world with a few actors in it and a camera

the ui collection would be rendered on top of view of the 3d worlds camera.

Comment: Maybe give example of what you want?

Comment: added a edit* @BlackCloud